# Random animations in WebGL

Tags: webgl

I have a WebGL scene with tens of thousands of polygons (2d on the z=0 plane).  Each polygon is composed of approximately 6-12 triangles (18-36 vertices).  I would like to apply a random (or random-looking) 3d animation to each shape by applying a 4x4 transformation matrix to all the vertices in each shape.

I know I could do this by assigning a 16 number matrix to each vertex (the same matrix for all 18-36 vertices in the shape).  I know this is just a bit the nature of WebGL but it seems somewhat inefficient to have 18-36 identical copies of the same 4x4 matrix.

I was wondering if there are any more efficient ways to do it.  For example, is there a way to use only say 20 matrices and randomly assign a matrix to each shape?  I am still learning webgl, so I am not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head I see three routes you can go,
all of them will require you to have at least one additional "index" attribute on your vertices to know what polygon they belong to(you can probably encode that as part of the position).

For when you need to control each animation individually:

1. Upload a bunch of transform matrices as uniforms, and index into it via additional shape index. if you really just want to alternate between a bunch of definable matrices this is probably the most efficient way of doing so.

For when you need to control each shape individually:

2. Upload a ton of matrices through a floating point RGBA texture, 4 pixels = 1 matrix, unpack the applicable matrix in the vertex shader using the shape index as an offset into the texture.

For when you don't need explicit control:

3. Procedurally animate your shapes in the vertex shader, use the shape index or maybe even just the position and a noise function in conjunction with a time uniform to generate your transform (matrix) on the fly, depending on the transform you need and your vertex- vs fragment shader load this can be the fastest method.

This last approach would go something like this (vertex shader code):

```c
float rotationY = noise(shapeIndex + time)*PI;
vec3 translation = vec3(
    noise(shapeIndex + 521 + time),
    noise(shapeIndex + 123 + time),
    noise(shapeIndex + 321 + time)
) * 2.0 - 1.0; // adjust this scaling depending on your projection 
mat4 transform = mat4(
    vec4(cos(rotationY),0,sin(rotationY),0),
    vec4(0,1,0,0),
    vec4(-sin(rotationY),0,cos(rotationY),0),
    vec4(translation, 1)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I have a question about #1.  Let's say I add an index to each vertex (say a number between 0 and 20), and then I have 20 uniform mat4s with names "transformMat4Number#".  Let's say I have a vertex that has been assigned an index of 8, then how would I identify the variable "transformMat4Number8" in the vertex shader?

Comment: You use a uniform array `uniform mat4 transforms[20]` and then index into it.